# getting null pointer exception in Kotlin Project

Tags: unit-testing, testing

@Test
fun `should record partial Withdrawal`() {
underTest.recordPartialWithdrawal(defaultUserId, Money.of(200.200, "EUR"), LocalDate.now())
val paymentRequestHistoryRequestCapture = argumentCaptor()

```
    verify(paymentRequestHistoryRepository).save<PaymentRequestHistory>(paymentRequestHistoryRequestCapture.capture())
    assertThat(paymentRequestHistoryRequestCapture.firstValue).satisfies(
        Consumer {
        assertThat(it.type).isEqualTo(PaymentRequestType.OUTGOING_PARTIAL_WITHDRAWAL)
        assertThat(it.userId).isEqualTo(defaultUserId)
        assertThat(it.amount).isEqualTo(Money.of(200.200, "EUR"))
    }
    )
```

underTest.recordPartialWithdrawal(defaultUserId, Money.of(200.200, "EUR"), LocalDate.now())

getting recordPartialWithdrawal ( can not be null error)

please tell me how to correct this

Comment: getting these errors

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: paymentRequestHistoryRep…t
            )
        ) must not be null